# Sklearn Gaussian Process Regressor Overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process

I am testing a set of regression algorithms and I'm having troubles with GPR. I have a set of 60 observations x 101 variables as a predictor (X) versus a set of 60 observations x 1 variable as a response (y). Given that the 101 elements of X represent multiple wavelengths of an hyperspectral dataset, I apply PCA to reduce collinearity.

I am running the following code

```
scaler=preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
xscaled=scaler.transform(X)
ncomps=2
pca=PCA(n_components=ncomps)
xpca=pca.fit_transform(xscaled)
```

later I run the GPR as following:

```
kernel=ConstantKernel(1.0) * RBF(1.0)
gpr=GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,normalize_y=False).fit(xpca,y)
y_gpr=gpr.predict(xpca)
r2g=r2_score(y,y_gpr)
mseg=mean_squared_error(y,y_gpr)
print('GPR: R2: %0.4f, MSE: %0.4f' %(r2g,mseg))
```

And the print result is

`GPR: R2: 1.0000, MSE: 0.0000`

Now that's clearly not a good result, but I do not understand how to make this better. Any suggestion would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts for regularising the model:

- Increase the `length_scale=` parameter of `RBF()`
- Increase the `alpha=` parameter value in `GaussianProcessRegressor()`
- Again for `alpha`, but specify `alpha=` as a vector instead, where you boost it for the data points where the model seems to overfit the most.

A plot of sample index vs. y, overlaid on sample index vs. prediction, could be helpful for visualisation.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to optimize this parameter with a gridsearch, but it seems that I cannot iterate over the length_scale. Even if I run it like 
`parameters={'alpha': [0.0001, 0.001,0.1,0.5,1,1.5],'kernel__length_scale':[100,1000,100000]}
gpr=GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=RBF(length_scale_bounds="fixed")) optm=GridSearchCV(gpr,parameters)` I still end up with `GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=RBF(length_scale=1))`

Comment: You're welcome. I assume you run `optm.fit(...)`? After that, the best parameters found will be in `optm.best_params_`, and the best fitted model (refitted on *all* the data) in `optm.best_estimator_`. Running `print(optm.best_estimator_.get_params())` or `print(optm.best_params_)` will report the best parameters.

Comment: About the search...another way of doing it when you don't know the right value is to use `RandomizedSearchCV`, which works best of you tell it the distribution to search over rather than a fixed list of values, e.g. `parameters={'kernel__length_scale': scipy.stats.loguniform(100, 100_000), 'alpha': scipy.stats.loguniform(1e-4, 1.5}`. Your approach is valid of course, but if you needed to search more finely the randomized approach takes less time.